# Refit variable on [Get("{route}")]

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core-3.1, refit

I'm having trouble with Refit using variables as path for a Get request

This is my super simple Get request

```
public interface IParceriaIntegracao
{
    [Get("/{caminho}")]
    Task<IntegracaoResponse> GetShow(string caminho);
}
```

This is my controller

```
[HttpGet]
    [Route("integrar")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetShow(string url)
    {
        try
        {
            Uri uri = new Uri(url);
            string hostCompleto = $"{uri.Scheme}://{uri.Host}";
            string caminho = $"{uri.AbsolutePath.Substring(1)}";

            var host = RestService.For<IParceriaIntegracao>(hostCompleto);

            var retorno = await host.GetShow(caminho);

            return await Response(retorno.Message);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

The host goes well and not problem, teoretically the rest of the path should too. I tried with and without substring, and with and without the / in the Get annotation.

But it's returning error 404, as my path seems not to work properly.

Any idea of what it could be, or how i could solve?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you're trying to access a route like, for example, `{baseAdress}/controller/integrar`. So, to access this route, in the interface you must also enter the route `integrar`, like this:

```
public interface IParceriaIntegracao
{
    [Get("/integrar")]
    Task<IntegracaoResponse> GetShow(string caminho);
}
```